# how can I Implement Lazy with Unity Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, unity-container, lazy-initialization

I have a class where I am injecting two service dependencies. I am using Unity container.

```
public UserService(ILazyInitialization<AClass> aCLass, ILazyInitialization<BClass> bClass) 
{ _aClass= aCLass; 
  _bClass= bClass; 
}
```

and **UnityCOnfig** is like

```
 container.RegisterType<IAClass, AClass>(); 
 container.RegisterType<IBCLass, BClass>();
```

I have created a Generic class for implement Lazy

```
 public class LazyInitialization<T> : ILazyInitialization<T> where T : class 
    {
        private static Lazy<T> _lazy;
         

        public static class LazyDefault
        {
            static Type listType = typeof(T);
            public static Lazy<T> Create<T>() where T : new()
            {
                return new Lazy<T>(() => Activator.CreateInstance<T>());
                return  new Lazy<T>(() => new T());
            } 
        }
```

This Generic class always retune **null** Lazy's Value.

I am calling this method from my service class like :-

```
LazyInitialization<AClass>.LazyDefault.Create<AClass>();
```

How do I implement it with Unity container?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the full source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others. It is unclear where exactly you get the `null` value and when/how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what is exactly your task, but, if you need instantiate object not at resolving stage but later, let say manually, you may use `Lazy<T>` instead of `ILazyInitialization<T>`:

```
// ... registration part ...
container.RegisterInstance<Lazy<IService>>(new Lazy<IService>(() => new Service()));

// another service
public class ServiceA : IServiceA
{
    private readonly Lazy<IService> _lazy;

    public ServiceA(Lazy<IService> lazyInstance)
    {
        _lazy = lazyInstance;
    }

    public void DoSmth()
    {
        // create instance
        var instance = _lazy.Value;
        // use instance below ...
    }
}
```